# What is the proper way to handle drupal_get_destination and drupal_goto?

Tags: 8, redirection

I am considering the following approach in my controller (the method which corresponds to a given route).

```
$destination = \Drupal::destination()->getAsArray();
if (isset($destination['destination'])) {
  return new RedirectResponse(Url::fromUri($destination['destination']));
}
else {
  return $this->redirect('acquia_connector.settings');
}
```

Should I use different code to handle both route based and URL based redirects?

Comment: Edit - updated to make it clear that I'm looking for the Drupal 8 approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal automatically uses destination, you don't have to do anything. If a destination argument is given, it will override default. So you can simplify your code to a simple, hardcoded $this->redirect(...).

The only exception is when you have links that you want to respect destination too (e.g. a cancel link on a confirm form), then you have to do it yourself. But the default confirm form already does that too AFAIK.

Comment: Could you point me to where is this destination override handled? I've been looking into ControllerBase::redirect, which invokes $this->getUrlGenerator()->generateFromRoute($route_name, $route_parameters, $options), which looks up the url_generator service and invokes the relevant generateFromRoute method, which is [this one](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21UrlGenerator.php/function/UrlGenerator%3A%3AgenerateFromRoute/8). But in this method I can't find the override either.

Comment: Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\RedirectResponseSubscriber is where this happens.